# Check if a list contains an item in Ansible

Tags: yaml, ansible

I'm trying to check if the version supplied is a valid supported version. I've set the list of acceptable versions in a variable, and I want to fail out of the task if the supplied version is not in the list. However, I'm unsure of how to do that.

```
#/role/vars/main.yml
---
  acceptable_versions: [2, 3, 4]
```

and

```
#/role/tasks/main.yml
---
  - fail: 
      msg: "unsupported version"
      with_items: "{{acceptable_versions}}"
      when: "{{item}} != {{version}}"

  - name: continue with rest of tasks...
```

Above is sort of what I want to do, but I haven't been able to figure out if there's a one line way to construct a "list contains" call for the fail module.

Answer (score 106, accepted):

You do not need `{{}}` in when conditions. What you are searching for is:

```
- fail: msg="unsupported version"
  when: version not in acceptable_versions
```

Comment: Where is this documented?

Comment: This only appears to work for exact string matches :(

Comment: Actually this is a feature of jinja2 and therefore in their documentation. See http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/2.9/templates/#other-operators

Comment: http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbooks_conditionals.html#the-when-statement

"[...]when clause, which contains a raw Jinja2 expression without double curly braces[..]"

Comment: Re: This only appears to work for exact string matches, try
 when: version not in acceptable_versions|to_json
works for a substring match for me.

Answer (score 13):

Ansible has a `version_compare` filter since 1.6.
You can do something like below in `when` conditional:

`when: ansible_distribution_version | version_compare('12.04', '>=')`

This will give you support for major & minor versions comparisons and you can compare versions using operators like:

`<, lt, <=, le, >, gt, >=, ge, ==, =, eq, !=, <>, ne`

You can find more information about this here: [Ansible - Version comparison filters](http://docs.ansible.com/playbooks_variables.html#version-comparison-filters)

Otherwise if you have really simple case you can use what @ProfHase85 suggested

Comment: I noticed this during my research, but the reason I didn't opt for this is because I wanted to be able to support a random list of #'s, which might be discontinuous I.e. 2, 7, 10, 11, and I didn't want to have to construct some crazy combination of operators